# How to temporarily redirect one site to another in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to temporarily redirect all traffic from one site to another and the following directives are not working. The source site still resolves.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sourcesite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://targetsite.com/ [R=302,NC,L]
```

Any suggestions on what might be wrong?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in `.htaccess`? Or any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Ah, it turned out to be something silly... I had a `[L]` on a rewrite condition higher up in the .htaccess file and I did not realize that prevented these directives from being handled.

Comment: As a general rule, external redirects (especially what is intended to be a "catch-all" redirect such as this) should go before internal rewrites at the top of the file. So, the order of the directives should be changed, rather than removing the `L` (`last`) flag on the preceding directive.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't have your `.htaccess` file enabled. Set `AllowOverride all` for the `<Directory>` that contains it. Your config is fine.